On what authority did Moses allow Reuben and Gad to settle east of the Jordan?
The tribes of Reuben and Gad wanted to settle on the east side of the Jordan River because the land there was more favorable for their abundant livestock.  In exchange, they promised Moses they will still fight with the rest of Israel until they are settled in Eretz Yisrael.  Moses tells them:

וִהְיִיתֶ֧ם נְקִיִּ֛ם מֵיְהֹוָ֖ה וּמִיִּשְׂרָאֵ֑ל וְ֠הָיְתָ֠ה הָאָ֨רֶץ הַזֹּ֥את לָכֶ֛ם לַאֲחֻזָּ֖ה לִפְנֵ֥י יְהֹוָֽה


[If you do this,] you shall be clear before the Lord and before Israel; and this land shall be your holding under the Lord. [Numbers 32:22]

God had made it clear He wanted all the Jews to settle in Eretz Yisrael.  East of the Jordan is not part of Eretz Yisrael, or there would have been no need for this discussion in the Torah and Moses should not have been standing there.  No mention is made of Moses consulting God and God's reaction is not recorded.  On what authority did Moses make such a momentous decision?
(Not quite the same question as this.)

The Or HaChaim HaKadosh explains: "The important thing was their motivation, as we have pointed out previously. As long as what they did was לשם שמים rather than for their own selfish motives even the people (10 tribes) would not harbour any bad feelings against these two tribes. Moses added the words: "this land will become your inheritance before G'd," that their participation in helping the other tribes to conquer and to settle on the West Bank would make their own lands safe against intruders." (1)

(2) "It is possible that by repeating the expression לפני השם, "in the presence of G'd," Moses meant to say that although their land was חוצה לארץ, "outside the boundaries of the Holy Land proper," they would be considered as if they had made their residence within the Holy Land. The land would be considered holy as no strip of secular land separated between it and ארץ ישראל proper." Or HaChaim, Bamidbar 32:22.

"God had made it clear He wanted all the Jews to settle in Eretz Yisrael. East of the Jordan is not part of Eretz Yisrael" See Genesis 9:18, Exodus 23:31, Deuteronomy 1:7-8 and 11:24, Joshua 1:3-4... although the plan was initially to start out west of the Jordan river, it was clearly also the plan that the territory should also eventually be expanded eastward.
